# C# Syntax Highlighter that outputs HTML

Tags: c#, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a C# syntax highlighter that will take my C# code and turn it into standalone HTML that is neatly tagged. I have found some websites that offer this but only output HTML that is coupled with a CSS stylesheet. If anyone knows if what I'm describing exists please gimme a link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [Copy Code in HTML format with Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/06/07/copy-code-in-html-format-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) as part of [Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/06/07/announcing-vs2010-productivity-power-tools-and-modeling-feature-packs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Python tool [Pygments](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpygments.org%2F&ei=ogdvTK7wOo-gvgPn_ohB&usg=AFQjCNGVIxeCqQ14mGgLNznFat5nyACb5Q&sig2=qAteY32rhuWeKP3oRTiVXQ) looks like it can do what you want and much more besides. I believe it supports many languages, including C#.

> - a wide range of common languages and markup formats is supported
> - special attention is paid to details that increase highlighting quality
> - support for new languages and formats are added easily; most
>     languages use a simple regex-based
>     lexing mechanism
> - a number of output formats is available, among them ***HTML***, RTF,
>     LaTeX and ANSI sequences
> - it is usable as a ***command-line tool and as a library***

Answer (score 0):

When I last used it, I got standalone HTML from the CopySourceAsHtml plugin to Visual Studio. (I stopped using it only because I prefer the linked CSS approach.)

http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/

The appeal of this plugin is that it will match the styling of your Visual Studio theme, whatever that may be.